# Increase response time for SYNC request

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

Since we have to get actual device names during response to the SYNC
request. It will probably takes more seconds to process which results
failure while syncing. If we don't include get device names then syncing
works fine.

Is there a way to increase response time for SYNC request.

Comment: can You show us your code or a code example?

Comment: app.onSync((body, headers) => {
//Initialise params to get username
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.getUser(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) {console.log(err, err.stack); }
else {    
//Initialise params get data from database   
documentClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
if(err) { console.log(err.message); }
else { 
// Received DATA...Store it
//////Get Device name didn't work for SYNC
iotdata.getThingShadow(params, function(err, data){
if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); }
else {
// Received DEVICE NAME
}});
///////////
}})}});
return {SYNC DATA}
});